# Facebook SDK AppRequests Error: OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I want to read the user's apprequest-id. I've already finish the function below:

1. get server token:

   ```
   url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{app_id}&client_secret=#{secret_key}&grant_type=client_credentials"
   ```
2. then, i built the function that sending user_token to server as {client_access_token}
3. So, I call this function to get AppRequest as json

   ```
   url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/#{fb_id}/apprequests/?input_token=#{client_access_token}&access_token=#{server_access_token}"
   ```

And i got this error:

```
     {
      "error": {
          "message": "(#15) Requires session when calling from a desktop app",
          "type": "OAuthException",
          "code": 15
         }
     }
```

At first, I think that there are something wrong with the URL calling or access token, but I've already test another graph api such as "/me/friends" and "/me/?fields=installed" with the same input_token and access_token. And, it works normally. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solve by using {client_access_token} as access_token :)

```
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/#{fb_id}/apprequests/?access_token=#{client_access_token}"
```